# Ansible Xml Module - Get xml value with namespace from a register

Tags: xml, xpath, ansible, xml-parsing

There is a pom.xml file, I use the following task to extract project name

```
- name: Loading project variables from the parent Maven pom.xml
  xml:
    path: "/some/path/pom.xml"
    namespaces:
      ns: "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xpath: "/ns:project/ns:name"
    content: text
  register: project_name_reg

- name: "Set project name"
  set_fact:
    project_name: "{{ project_name_reg.matches[0] }}"
```

It works, now `project_name` contains:

```
"project_name": {
        "{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}name": "My Project Parent"
    }
```

How to extract the real `My Project Parent` value by this complicated `{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}name` name with namespace? It is a simple dictionalry, but all my tries fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't care about that key at all. You can just do this:

```
- name: "Set project name"
  set_fact:
    project_name: "{{ project_name_reg.matches[0].values()|first }}"
```

Comment: it is closer, but I get `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: dict_values object has no element 0` If I remove the last `[0]`, the result is: `"project_name": "dict_values(['My Project Parent'])"`

Comment: here is the solution: `{{ project_name_reg.matches[0].values() | first }}` please correct your answer, I mark it, as the right solution.